# Excel Formula Referencing

Tags: excel-formula

quick excel question:

If I put values in cell B1 and B2.
Then write the following formula in cell A1:
=$B$1-$B$2

then I highlight cells B1 and B2 and move them to column C. the formula in A1 automatically adjusts for the move ie. formula now becomes:
=$C$1-$C$2

How would I get it to stick to column B and not switch to column C. I tried searching google but did not get right answers (probably am not phrasing question correctly).

The context of my problem is that formulas in one sheet are being calculated based on month end data which is placed in another sheet. Now I need to add April month end data. So I shift the old data to the right and input April's data, but the formulas are automatically adjusting for the shift and still refer to March's month-end data. This despite the formulas using absolute referencing.

Thanks for any help provided

Answer (score 1):

The formula you are looking for is

```
=INDIRECT("B1")-INDIRECT("B2")
```

This will always refer to Cells B1 and B2 regardless of what you to do move the cells or add new columns etc.

This will allow you to simply insert a column for the new month.

Answer (score 0):

Not a good spreadsheet design, you should really add new data to a new column.

However, if you are determined to stick to that design, copy and paste the old values to a new column, then delete the originals.  Formulas will not be alterd by that.

Comment: Thank you Chris. That does work. Would you mind describing what a better spreadsheet design would be, please?

Comment: Like I said, put your new data for the new month in a new column.  Leave each months data where it is after its entered.

Comment: ah ok. And to get the formulas to refer to the newly added column/month-end? Would the match function using the month-end (and then perhaps using offset) be the best way to go about that? Thank you for the advice Chris